# How do I disable ICMP echo responses within a Docker container?

Tags: docker, networking

I want to be able to change the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` file from within my Docker container, but I get the

> bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all: Read-only file system

error when attempting to do so, and running Docker with the `--privileged` flag is not an option.

Is there any way I can disable (and preferably also reenable) ICMP echo requests from within my container?

Answer (score -2):

Here are the steps to change to disable ICMP echo response within Docker container:

1. connect to the container with all privileges

```
    docker exec -it --privileged container_name bash
```

2. modify the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` file via the `systl` conmmand, by default value is `0`

See default value :

```
    sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Disable icmp echo response :

```
    sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

Comment: As I mentioned, running docker with the `--privileged` flag is not an option.

Comment: Add docker help: `docker exec --help` and show me response please

Comment: That's a horrible idea, even if so because you're setting that not for the host. There is no point in running that in a container. Your basically running a privileged container to access the host's kernel and disabling ICMP for it.